# WordPress and WooCommerce How to Assign Attribute Based Pricing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I have an installation of WooCommerce and I'm looking to set up a product which would have a base price and options to select the following:

- Colour (20 colours)
- Cushions (20 colours)
- Legs (5 leg types)

I would like to have a base price and prices for each of the options

Is this achievable and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your products as variable products. This allows you to add attributes and create variations from those attributes, each with it's own metadata.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/